# Why is MLP working similar to RNN for text generation

Tags: neural-network, rnn, nlp, language-model

I was trying to perform text generation using only a character level feed-forward neural network after having followed [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) which uses LSTM. I one-hot encoded the characters of my corpus which gave a vector of length 45. Then I concatenated every 20 characters and fed this 20*45 length vector as input to an MLP with the 21st character's one hot as the output.

Thus my X (input data) shape is -> (144304, 900)
and my Y (output data) shape is -> (144304, 45)

Here's the output from my code:

> alice was beginning very about a grible thing was and bet she with a
>   great come and fill feel at and beck to the darcht repeat allice
>   waited it, put this was not an encir to the white knew the mock turtle
>   with a sigh. ‘i only took the regular cours was be crosd it to fits
>   some to see it was and getting she dodn as the endge of the evence,
>   and went on to love that you were no alway not--ohe f whow to the
>   gryphon is, who denight to goover and even stried to the dormouse, and
>   repeated her question. ‘why did they live at the bottom of a well?’
>
> ‘tabl the without once it it howling it the duchess to herself it as
>   eng, longing one of the door and wasting for the homend of the taits.’
>
> ‘sthing i cancus croquet with the queen to-day?’
>
> ‘i should like it very much,’ said the dryphon, ‘you first form into a
>   line along-the sea-shore--’
>
> ‘the right!’ cried the queen nother frowing tone. any the this her for
>   some thing is and at like the look of it at all,’ said the king:
>   ‘however, it may kiss my hand if it likes.’
>
> ‘i’d really feeer that in a few this for some whele wish to get thing
>   to eager to think thcapered twice, and shook note bill herself in a
>   lell as expectant, and thowedd all have come fuconfuse it the march
>   hare: she thought it must be the right way of speaking to a mouse: she
>   had never done such a thing before, but she remembered having seen in
>   her brother’s latin grammar, ‘a mouse--of a mouse--to a mouse--a
>   mouse--o mister once to hin fent on the words with her fane with ale
>   three king the said, and diffich a vage and so mane alice this cime.

My Question is why is MLP working similar to an RNN/LSTM. What's the advantage of using RNN/LSTM for such tasks over MLP?